# Rational number SAT

Tags: elementary-set-theory, irrational-numbers

Which of the following has an element that is less than any another element in that set?

I. The set of positive rational numbers

II. The set of positive rational numbers $r$ such that $r^2$ is greater than or equal to $2$

III. The set of positive rational numbers such that $r^2 > 4$.

The answer is None.

I am not very clear why.  Can anyone please explain intuitively? I know that there is no such thing as the smallest positive rational number.

Comment: The question can be rewritten as follows: "Which of the following has a smallest element?". But as you wrote on the post, 'there is no such thing as the smallest positive rational number' which is why None of the choices has a smallest element.

Comment: If $r^2 > 4$ then $r> 2$ and hence $r - 2 > 0$. Since $r-2$ is a rational number, there is no smallest value.

Comment: My hint is a clearer version of zxcvber's and The Chaz 2.0's comments. Do you think my answer helps?

Comment: Between any two distinct real numbers $a,b$ (*with $a<b$*) there exists a rational number $q$ strictly between them, i.e. $a<q<b$.  This is what we mean by saying the rational numbers are "dense."  Now, Suppose there *was* a smallest rational $s$ in each of these sets: call it $b$, for (I) that would mean $0<s$, but by density there is a $q$ where $0<q<s$.  Similarly for (II) that would say $\sqrt{2}\leq s$ but $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational so $\sqrt{2}\neq s$ so $\sqrt{2}<s$, but by density there is a rational $q$ where $\sqrt{2}<q<s$... etc...

Comment: You should look into the Well Ordering Principle

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't think this would count as an intuitive answer, as required.

Comment: What is unintuitive about density?  I would think the density of the rationals is a very intuitive (*and frankly obvious*) concept.  Picture it as "zooming in" on the real number line and there is clearly space between the two points.

Comment: @JMoravitz I meant that without an analogy your comment would not be intuitive. Thanks for including this bit of extra information.

Comment: This has a lot to do with cardinality. These all have cardinality$\aleph_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" 'there is no such thing as the smallest positive rational number' which is why None of the choices has a smallest element."  Be a *little* careful!  The is no smallest rational number but a *set* of rational numbers could have a smallest element *in the set*.

Example:  The set of rational numbers $r$ so that $r \ge 5$ has a smallest element.  $r = 5$ is in the set and it is the smallest element in the set.

Of the set of all rational numbers so that $r^2 \le 0$.  That set has only *one* element at all. $0$.  $O$ is the smallest element in *that* set.

Okay, but what about the questions in the exercise:

I) The set of positive rational numbers.

There is no smallest positive rational number so no, the set doesn't have a smallest element.

If asked why, you should be able to justify it.  If $r$ is in the set then $\frac r2 < r$ is also in the set, so none can be smallest.

II) The set of all positive rational numbers so that $r^2 \ge 2$.

$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational so for any rational number, $r$ either $r^2 < 2$ or $r^2 > 2$.  So for any $r^2 > 2$ there is another $\sqrt 2< s < r$ and $s^2 > 0$ so there is no smallest element.

But NOTE.  If the question was all rational numbers so that $r^2 \ge 4$ that *does* have a smallest element.  If $r = 2$ then $r^2 \ge 4$ and for any number $q < 2$ then $q^2 < 4$ so $2$ is the smallest element of the set.

III.  The set of all positive rationals where $r^2 > 4$.  This is just the set where $r > 2$.  It has no smallest as there is always some $2< s < r$ for any rational $r > 2$.

Comment: Yes.   I just needed to show there is number between 2 and r.  I needed to call it something, so I called it s.

Comment: Well done @fleablood! I just realised your answer was very detailed answer that explains my post better.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

An important point for these types of questions are understanding the properties of rational numbers. For example, by contradiction, question I is not true. Let us suppose there is a smallest positive rational number $\frac{p}{q}$. We can multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ to get $\frac{p}{2q}$. However, this is smaller than $\frac{p}{q}$, so there is no such thing as 
"the smallest positive rational number" (that is larger or smaller than a given value).

Can you use a similar type of argument for questions II and III with the appropriate bounds, which are $r>\sqrt2$ for question II and $r>2$ for question III?

Note: The negative root is not required because the question specifies the numbers have to be positive.

Comment: " I am now convinced of the idea that there is no such thing as a positive rational number"  wha... of course there are!  "why wouldn't statement I yield a rational number such as 1/999 "  Because we can then get 1/2000, or 1/4000, or 1/9999999999999999999999999999999.  None of those are the *smallest*

Comment: You have written the question wrong. (See zxcvber's comment.) The question should be "Which sets have a smallest element?"

Comment: @fleablood pointed this out. When a number $x$ is compared to a given number $n$ (which are distinct), the only case the difference between $x$ and $n$ can be minimised is when $x - n = 0$, or when $x = n$. However, $x$ and $n$ would be the same number, which contradicts the fact they are distinct.

Comment: Another point is that you are comparing numbers in the same set. It wouldn't be terribly useful to change the question now when there has been so much discussion and hard work answering your question right?

Comment: "why wouldn't statement I yield a rational number such as 1/999 which is smaller than a rational number gotten from statement III such as 11/5?"  Set I does have elements that are smaller than all the elements in sets II or III and II has elements that are smaller then all the elements of III and the set All rationals in [-2, 1] has elements that are smaller than all the elements of set I.  But that's ... completely irrelevant and has nothing whatsoever to do with what was  asked.  The are asking which sets have elements smaller than the elements in the *same* set.  Other sets don't matter.

Comment: I actually typed the question word for word from the college board SAT test. I just did not list out all the other incorrect answer choices.

Comment: I see now. I was comparing the elements from set to set. This question was confusing.

Comment: I meant to say that  I am now convinced of the idea that there is no such thing as the smallest positive rational number.

Comment: Yes.  There is no smallest positive number.  In fact, for any value there no smallest rational (or real) that is bigger than it.  But the value itself is the smallest number *equal* or greater than than the value.

Comment: Key to realize.  Between any two numbers there is always a rational number between them.  That means there can't be any smallest number that is *strictly* between them.